# I can sign into remote phpmyadmin with my credentials, but when I try and connect to the db in phpstorm, I get rejected password

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, phpstorm

I can connect fine in phpymyadmin in the remote database server fine. I want to have access to the db in phpstorm to make coding a bit easier but I keep getting rejected password. Im using the exact same credentials I am ussing to sign into phpymadmin. Could this be the server configuration? I know nothing about that. I wont be able to speak to the server admins until tomorrow so I won't be able to ask them about it. Would be nice to have it working now.

Furthermore, the code on the webserver does not seem to talk to the database. Again, I am using the same credentials to sign in with the php code.

It was working flawlessly on localhost, but now since I've moved it over to a remote web server and database, nothing seems to be working correctly.

Comment: > remote web server and database
Can you tell us more about the remote web server and database? Are you using just like normal website hosting or something like AWS?

Comment: Its a server hosting by my school. I guess what I'm really trying to ask here if it's possible to have different credentials to log into phpmyadmin to edit the database and to actually access the database for CRUD operations (mysqli connection in php)

Comment: Yes - generally PhpMyAdmin allows you to administrate many databases - each database itself will need to have users added. You can do this via PhpMyAdmin - a quick search of "add user to MySQL database" should set you in the right direction - make sure you give the user enough permissions to do what you need.

Comment: Make sure the host you're connecting from matches the host field in the user's account settings. For instance, if you're connecting from phpMyAdmin on 192.168.100.25 but phpstorm is on a machine at 192.168.100.50, a host field matching exactly 192.168.100.25 won't allow the other machine to connect. Likewise if one is using 'localhost' or the socket connection and the other is using TCP/IP networking.